# Telegram does not show the preview

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

We designed a bot which aggregates and sends related pages to clients. So we are sending lots of links starting with [www.melkradar.com](http://www.melkradar.com).
But unfortunately, at some point, Telegram stopped showing our links preview.
So, now if you send a link from our website it will not show any preview for it.

What is the reason that Telegram is not showing the preview for [www.melkradar.com](http://www.melkradar.com) anymore? What can I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BIG size images for your website as a featured image it won't show. But if you use small-size images (like less than 100Kb) for your website the preview will appear in your Telegram when you post the link.

---

You can see the sample posts I did before using a small-size image and after using a small-size image:

[image]